# Ruby on Rails using counter, i.e. "i", in a variable name

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form in Rails where users can enter multiple records. I am going to write some JavaScript where users can have a virtually unlimited number of records.  My hash is going to look like this:

```
inputA_1, inputB_1, inputC_1
inputA_2, inputB_2, inpuctC_2
```

In my controller I want to do a `while` loop to iterate through the rows and save them to the database, for example:

```
z = 0
i = 1
while z = 0
  @inputA = [:params][:inputA_i]
  @inputB = [:params][:inputB_i]
  @inputC = [:params][:inputC_i]
  if @inputA.nil?
     z=1
  else
  @record = [inputA: @inputA, inputB: @inputB, inputC: @inputC]
  @record.save
  i = i + 1
  end
end
```

The problem is that I don't know how to make the "`i`" of `:inputA_i` be the value of `i`.

Any help in that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpolate `i` into a string and convert string to `symbol`:

```
@inputA = [:params]["inputA_#{i}".to_sym]
@inputB = [:params]["inputB_#{i}".to_sym]
@inputC = [:params]["inputC_#{i}".to_sym]
```

Comment: I thought you could do that with symbol literals `:"..."` without `to_sym`.

Comment: Yes, `:"inputA_#{i}"` will also work. I wanted to make it clear to the OP what was being done.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest array serialization of form elements instead?:

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="inputA[]" value="Hi">
  <input type="hidden" name="inputA[]" value="There">
  <input type="hidden" name="inputA[]" value="Sir">
</form>
```

When a form with that HTML gets submitted, the values get turned into an array on the params hash:

```
params[:inputA] #=> ["Hi", "There", "Sir"]
```

So all your JavaScript has to do is create more inputs that have the same name, ending in `[]`. Processing these inputs in the controller is *much* simpler.

```
params[:inputA].each do |value|
  @record = Record.new
  @record.inputA = value
  @record.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a string like this

```
"hello #{name}"
```

or

```
"%s means %s" %["how do you do?", "hello"]
```

hope it can help!