# ruby on rails select a variable name using loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, variables

There's a similar answer but it won't apply to me, but maybe will help someone: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482983/ruby-on-rails-using-counter-i-e-i-in-a-variable-name)

So, I have a loop and need to input a value into each of 20 variables, called `product1, product2, ... , product20`.

Im using nokogiri to change the values from a page, and manually it works:

```html
    li.content = @site.product1
    li = @doc.css('li')[1]
```

But to avoid code repetition and also I have more cases like that one in my app im trying to make a loop, but it won't work since now.

What it need to do:

```html
(1..20).each do |i|
    li = @doc.css('li')[i]
    li.content = @site.producti
end
```

Thanks

Comment: what you mean by won't work

Comment: `li.content = @site.produtoi` is that a typing mistake

Comment: oh, sorry, it was a mistake, yes

Comment: just fixed that issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRy

```
(0...20).each do |i|
    li = @doc.css('li')[i]
    li.content = @site.send("product#{i}")
end
```

Comment: Hello, wont work, gives: "undefined method `product' for" ... "undefined method `product' for"

Comment: Actually what you want `@site.product1` this should also change like 1, 2 , 3 or `produtoi`

Comment: I want @site.product1, sorry to make it confusing